# Saving pandas panels with to_pickle, loading error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panel in pandas:

```
a0
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 1 (items) x 10 (major_axis) x 7 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0.0 to 0.0
Major_axis axis: 0.0 to 20.0
Minor_axis axis: Alpha to Cn tot
```

I save the panel with

```
a0.to_pickle('qq.pkl')
```

To read it, I use:

```
a0=pd.read_pickle('qq.pkl')
```

When I read the file for the first time, there are no problems, but the second one gives me this output:

```
 a0=pd.read_pickle('qq.pkl')
  File "/home/pt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py", line 37, in read_pickle
    return pkl.load(fh)
UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered,
but no persistent_load function was specified.
```

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong? (I am on CentOS, python 2.7, pandas 0.12.0)

Edit: How I created the panel:

```
data1[al][ma]={'delta_PsPinf':delta_PsPinf,'Cz ClarckY':Cz_CY,'Cz NACA':Cz_NA,'Cz CY+NA':np.array(Cz_CY)+np.array(Cz_NA),'Fx':Fx,'Fy':Fy,'Fz':Fz,'Fz_adim':Fz_adim, 'Cz_tot': np.array(Cz_CY)+np.array(Cz_NA)+np.array(Fz_adim),'Hi':Hi,'Hi/f':Hi/array(force) }
    
    
a0=pd.Panel(data1[0.0])
a0.major_axis=force
a0.major_axis.name='force' 
a0.minor_axis.name='var'  
a0.sort_index(axis=2,ascending=False)
a0.to_excel('qq.xlsx')            
a0.to_pickle('qq.pkl')
```

The postprocessing:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.rc('font', size=14.0)
import matplotlib.cm as cm


def plottingg(a,var,h,strr):
    h.hold(True)
    ii=0
    for i in a.items:
        c = cm.jet(ii*int(255/len(a0.items)),1) 
        q=a[i].plot(y=var,style=strr,label=[var+' Mach '+str(i)],color=c)
        
        ii=ii+1    
    plt.xlabel('force')
    q.legend(loc=2)
    h.hold(False)

   
h=plt.figure()    
a0=pd.read_pickle('qq.pkl')
a2=pd.read_pickle('qqq.pkl')
plottingg(a0,'Cz_tot',h,'--o')
plottingg(a0,'Cz CY+NA',h,'-*')
plt.show(True)
```

Comment: Are you doing anything with file in between first and second reads?

Comment: I add some columns, save the result to excel (.to_excel) and plot them,but I don't save again

Comment: This error would only happen if you try to read from a pickle file that's open and had already been read (e.g. the file pointer is at the end). ``read_pickle`` closes the file properly in 0.12. Can you post how you created this panel? can you post the pickle file on dropbox?

Comment: I added the details you requested in the main post